# mysql query execution time - can i get this in milliseconds?

Tags: mysql, execution-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get load time in milliseconds or microseconds in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120402/how-to-get-load-time-in-milliseconds-or-microseconds-in-mysql)

I'm comparing a few different approaches to getting some data in mysql, directly at the console, using the SQL_NO_CACHE option to make sure mysql keeps running the full query every time.  Mysql gives me the execution time back in seconds, to two decimal places.  I'd really like to get the result back in milliseconds (ideally to one or two decimal places), to get a better idea of improvements (or lack of).  Is there an option i can set in mysql to achieve this?

thanks, max

Comment: Yes, time in seconds seems silly for most uses since "most uses" means web sites - and their queries should be under a second!

Answer (score 11):

The answer is to enable the [mysql profiler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) and then check it after you run your queries.

```
mysql> set profiling=1;
```