# how to get load time in milliseconds or microseconds in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I' ve searched and searched, but I wasn't able to find an easy way to get this:

```
Query OK, 50000 rows affected (0.35 sec)
```

in milliseconds or microseconds.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Since mysql don't support miliseconds on a DateTime row, it probably don't support miliseconds anywhere.

Comment: [Xeoncross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99923/xeoncross)'s answer in [this closed post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644592/1388418) shows how to get sub-second MySQL execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That time's calculated by the mysql monitor application and isn't done by the mysql server. It's not something you can retrieve programatically by doing (say) `select last_query_execution_time()` (which would be nice).

You can simulate it in a coarse way by doing the timing in your application, by taking system time before and after calling the query function. Hopefully the client-side overhead would be minimal compared to the mysql portion.

Comment: why it says ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION mydb.last_query_execution_time does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I came with the same problem, I did my queries from a linux console using [time](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/time.1.html)

```
$ time mysql --user="user" -D "DataBase" -e "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(1) FROM table"

 ------------
 count(1)
 ------------
 750
 ------------

 real 0m0.269s
 user 0m0.014s
 sys  0m0.015s
```

or

```
$ time -f"%e" mysql --user="user" -D "DataBase" -e "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(1) FROM table"

------------
 count(1)
------------
 750
------------
 0.24
```

It gives different values from "mysql" but at least is something you can work with, for example this script:

```
#!/bin
temp = 1
while [ $temp -le 1000]
do
    /usr/bin/time -f"%e" -o"/home/admin/benchmark.txt" -a mysql --user="user" -D "DataBase" -e "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(1) FROM table"  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    let temp=$temp+1
done
```

Execute the query 1000 times, *-f* shows only the real time, *-o* the output file, *-a* appends to the output, *> /dev/null 2> /dev/null* ignores the query output so it doesn't print in console each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could time it yourself in the code that runs the query:

Pseudo code:

```
double StartTime = <now>
Execute SQL Query 
double QueryTime = <now> - StartTime
```