# Maximum records table can handle to get results in 0 seconds while searching by primary key

Tags: mysql, performance

i am working on big data set.
and would like to know is there a number or how many maximum records a table can handle where if i search by `primary key` i will get result in `0 second`.

using latest `mysql`.
all queries are `read queries`, so i am using `myisam` .
current record count  is 903,520,165
my table structure is like this

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| lock        | char(45) | NO   |     |         |       |
| key         | char(28) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

there will be 10-500 select queries per second.

the only requirement is result should be returned within `0.00 seconds`.

so what factors affect the time taken by query to return `result` ?

i am using latest `centos x64` , `64 GB RAM`, `SSD`.

all queries are like

```
select lock from table where key = 'nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn';
```

should i just keep adding records and keep testing if results are returned in `0.00 second` and if the query time increases then stop adding new records , something like this ?
or there are other factors too ?

or there better `mysql engine` or `better db engine` available , its like

```
key->value store
```

---

**update 1:**

when i mean `0 seconds` i mean less than `20 milliseconds` or max `20-50 milliseconds`

---

**update 2 :**

i am not sure, but should i be looking for

```
Fastest, non-memory-based, multi-process key-value store
```

---

**update 3 :**

there are only reads , no inserts, no updates , no deletes.
and only select queries with limit to 1 results searching by primary key.

---

**update 4 :**

i have created 2 tables with small set of 500k records, 1 is myisam while another is innodb.

```
myisam (1 total, Query took 0.0000 seconds.)
innodb (1 total, Query took 0.0100 seconds.)
```

i am checking this on widnows test machine, on wamp

---

**update 5 :**

checked from mysql console on windows, and both myisam and innodb gave output in `[1 row in set (0.00 sec)].`

but i need timings in milliseconds.

---

**update 6 :**

its been 36 hours, since `alter table` to `innodb` has started . current state `copy to tmp table`.

---

**update 7 :**

i tried queries with `SQL_NO_CACHE`

myisam

```
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

innodb

```
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**update 8:**

to get timinigs in milliseconds i tried `last_query_execution_time()` from [how to get load time in milliseconds or microseconds in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120402/how-to-get-load-time-in-milliseconds-or-microseconds-in-mysql)

output

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION mydb.last_query_execution_time does not exist.
```

Comment: You can't accomplish anything in zero time. Perhaps you would like to state a more realistic constraint.

Comment: Why do you think 0.00 means anything in particular? How is that a requirement? MyISAM is deprecated. Fast keys are small, eg ints. Performance is very dependent on details, so we can't tell you more than you can find. You are not clear about "key->value store".

Comment: Many factors affect execution time, e.g. availible cpu power (differs as sometimes other tasks use it), my.cnf settings, number of querys at time (multiuser), .... You never can guarantee a min time. I would guess a integer PK should be faster than char. You have to test different settings and then compare times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change the question to "How can I speed up my key-value table with the following specs?".

You can get about 1 disk hit on a rotating HDD (as opposed to SSD).

So the answer is

- If the index block and data block are not cached, 0 rows (need 2 disk hits for MyISAM) -- in 10ms  (50 rows/sec)
- If *either, but not both* of those blocks is cached, 1 row -- in 10ms (100 rows/sec)
- As long as both blocks are cached for the desired, then hundreds of rows.  (thousands/sec)

For 50ms, MyISAM can deliver only 2-3 rows in worst case.  Perhaps we should switch to "How many rows/second as the metric"?

Next clarification.  Are you talking about many connections, each asking for a single row?  Or are you talking about one connection asking for consecutive (according to `PRIMARY KEY`) rows?

For more speed:

- Don't use `CHAR` unless the strings are actually fixed length.  Use `VARCHAR`.  This shrinks the index and data, thereby making them more cacheable.
- Change from MyISAM to InnoDB.  InnoDB "clusters" the PK with the data.  That is, when you find the PK, the data is right there.  This eliminates the first case, above.  Now the "worst case" is 5 rows in 50ms.  The best case is *perhaps* better than MyISAM.  (There are a lot of benchmarks out there; probably none exactly matches your situation.)

Another clarification needed:  Will you be updating rows?  Deleting rows?  Adding new rows?  These matter when it comes to fragmentation (which MyISAM w/VARCHAR is severely subject to and InnoDB is only slightly subject to).

Size analysis:

- MyISAM w/CHAR:  Data: 75 bytes/row * 903M rows + Index: ~60*903M = ~ 120GB.  Too much to be fully cached, even too much to keep the index in RAM (`key_buffer_size`).
- MyISAM w/VARCHAR:  Not knowing the typical size, nor the churn, I hesitate to compute.  But I suspect it would still be too much for 64GB of RAM.
- InnoDB w/VARCHAR:  No index needed other than `PRIMARY KEY(key)`.  Still the footprint might be ~120GB.  So, again, it cannot be fully cached (`innodb_buffer_pool_size`).

Next Clarification:  How 'random' are the `key` values used?  Will you be repeating the same ones a lot?  Or are they like UUIDs/MD5s (*very* random) and you will be bouncing around a lot.

If very random, then let's analyze the likelihood of something being in cache.  Let's say the lookup is in an index that is twice as big as what is cached in RAM.  This means that only half the time you will find the item in cache.  Now my answer is...

- With 50% cached, you have a disk hit the other 50%, and 50ms with InnoDB will give you an *average* of 10 rows per 50ms.  (200 rows per second (average) on HDD).
- If the index were 20 times as big as the cache, 95% would be cache misses.  That is you would be seriously I/O-bound.  (105 rows/sec for InnoDB)

Another clarification... Can the key and/or the lock be compressed in any way?

- Hex can be `UNHEXed` to half its size.
- Is `CHAR` defaulting to `utf8` when `ascii` would suffice?  (Factor of 3 in space for `CHAR`!!  I did not consider this in the computation above.)
- Are the strings the sort that would benefit from `COMPRESS()`?  In some studies, I have seen "almost any text longer than 10 bytes can benefit from `COMPRESS`".  English text or code or XML typically shrinks by about 3x.  Your 45 chars might shrink to 20.

If you could cut the table size in half, now you have a chance of caching everything.  This would take you from 200 rows/second (InnoDB) to thousands.

Comment: No.  That is "case insensitive" (...ci) = `A` would match `a`.  Instead, `ascii_bin`

Comment: i tried on small set, myisam returns record in 0.0000 seconds as per phpmyadmin while innodb returns record in 0.0200 second, still innodb better ? why ?

Comment: "0.0000" sounds bogus -- as if the Query cache were turned on in and in use.  Add a space in the middle of the query and time it again.  (A space is enough to fool the QC into thinking it is a different query.)

Comment: checked again with different primary key, myisam (1 total, Query took 0.0000 seconds.), innodb (1 total, Query took 0.0100 seconds.) i am checking this on widnows test machine, on wamp.

Comment: update i checked from mysql console on windows, and both myisam and innodb gave output in [1 row in set (0.00 sec)].

Comment: its been 36 hours, since alter table to innodb has started . current state copy to tmp table. how long will it take ?

Comment: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` bypasses the QC, and will get 'honest' timings.

Comment: There is no reliable way to estimate how long an `ALTER` will take.

Comment: okie., alter table took 5+ days. what's better 100 concurrent connections or 1 connection and 100 select queries. in terms of performance. calling from cpp . thanks

Comment: 20 'concurrent' connections doing `SELECTs` is possibly optimal.  1 connection would take longer (elapsed time) to finish.  100 connections might stumble over each other.  100 connections that each do only a single `SELECT` would be wasteful because of the overhead of making & breaking the connection.

Comment: As for the 5+ days; that seems excessive.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, how many rows, GB of data, Amount of RAM, settings of `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: innodb buffer pool size was default, so may be it was the case. as i had no other innodb table. near about billion rows. 4 gigs of ram, key_buffer_size was default too.

Comment: For 4GB and _all_ MyISAM:  key_buffer=600M, buffer_pool=0; for 4GB and _all_ InnoDB:  key_buffer=20M, buffer_pool=1600M.  Defaults were designed for much smaller hardware.  While transitioning, use numbers in between those.

Comment: err, i meant 64 gigs of RAM, sorry for typo.

Comment: Then the defaults are really a waste.  Set the key_buffer to 4G and the buffer_pool to 30G.  This will be good for all MyISAM / transition / and all InnoDB.  You can rethink the layout later.