# Is MySQL now() interval in milliseconds possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to only select the rows within 500 MS but I'm not sure if this is even possible with just MySQL?

My current code is:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT chat_user, chat_msg FROM chat_msg 
                          WHERE chat_id = ? 
                          AND chat_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND) 
                          AND chat_user != ?');
```

I was unable to insert that in a code block.

Comment: welcome. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/6102744/1415724 --- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2825838/1415724 --- https://stackoverflow.com/q/9624284/1415724 - I think the last one could be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's `DATE_SUB` function (documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)) accepts `MICROSECOND` as one of the interval type, so you can subtract 500 * 1000 microseconds and convert it into `Timestamp`, e.g.:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT chat_user, chat_msg FROM chat_msg 
                          WHERE chat_id = ? 
                          AND chat_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 500000 MICROSECOND) 
                          AND chat_user != ?');
```

If `chat_time` is of `Timestamp` type, you can use `TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 500000 MICROSECOND);` or `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 500000 MICROSECOND);` in the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Thank you. I should have said that I was using DATETIME, but this works for DATETIME aswell.

Answer (score 2):

To convert and select time into milliseconds Use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function.

```
SELECT chat_user, chat_msg, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(chat_time)*1000) As chattime FROM chat_msg
```

UNIX_TIMESTAMP will get you seconds and you need to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.